# Add same product for different-2 category in cart

Tags: magento2, category, cart

I am new in Magento, Using version 2. I am adding a same product to many different-2 categories.
I need to track orders which product was added to cart from each of these categories or was it added outside of these categories.

how can i pass category id (as a hidden input ) in add to cart function.
and want to add product as new in cart if category is different.
something like that :-

[image]

If anyone have solutions appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: You need to used magento event observer for this.

Comment: which event observer i need to use for cart function ?

Comment: you need to used this event  "checkout_cart_product_add_after"

Comment: thanks,how can i set checkout session with category id?

Comment: In this event code you can set variable into the session and access this variable according to your requirement.